# How to click element by class name using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, jquery-selectors

I have opened https://web.whatsapp.com . I want to click the "New Chat" button using JS. I tried searching using class name but it's not clicking. Why ?

Please remove space after https in link.

Screenshot of icon: http:// image.prntscr.com/image/0668dd3c273a484ab997a4ad8331fedd.png

What I have done so far from chrome console,

`var opennewchat = document.getElementsByClassName("icon icon-chat");
opennewchat[0].click();`

Inspect Element Screenshot: http:// image.prntscr.com/image/5cb835ac06f248008401bacc8a80ecf7.png

But this is not working :/ Any idea why ?

Comment: `querySelector` is quite useful in this scenario `document.querySelector(".icon.icon-chat").click()`

Comment: Still it is not clicking.